# Test if an Alias is a Template in D 2.0

Tags: templates, d

How do I test if an alias is a template in D 2.0?

```
template isTemplate(alias T)
{
    enum bool isTemplate = ???;
}
```

---

**Update:**

It should work like:

```
struct S(T)
{
    int opCall() { return 0; }
    int opUnary(string s)() if (s == "-") { return 0; }
}

pragma(msg, isTemplate!(S));                 //Should print true
pragma(msg, isTemplate!(S!(int)));           //Should print false
pragma(msg, isTemplate!((S!(int)).opCall));  //Should print false
pragma(msg, isTemplate!((S!(int)).opUnary)); //Should print true
```

For reference, things that *don't* work:

- You can't use any expression like `T!(...)` because you don't know what to put in place of the ellipses.
- You can't say `&T` because that also doesn't work if you're just given a plain old type name.

Comment: I'm courious for what purpose this can be useful. Usually to work with something (T) you need to have at least some knowledge what it is. I suppose you are just exploring the language ?

Comment: you can also take a look at related topic - Get template and its instantiation parameters - http://www.digitalmars.com/d/archives/digitalmars/D/learn/Get_template_and_its_instantiation_parameters_17854.html

Comment: @Michal: It's useful because I need to know whether `__traits(allMembers, T)` is returning an actual member that will exist at run time, or just a template name that may not exist at run time. Thanks for the link also, but it unfortunately didn't answer the question.

Comment: Next time when asking question, be please more verbose. It will help when you put question into context of what you are trying to achieve and include additional constraints you can think of. It helps quite much to to include piece of code from call site.The example you included in question is misleading. Thanks.

Comment: @Michal: Hm... what's "misleading" about my example? It's *exactly* what I need -- that is, if you actually follow it and don't change what I'm asking by adding new arguments, etc... your second answer was great except that it's got a few loopholes. :\

Comment: Now use `__traits(isTemplate, MyInstantiation)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This passes all except 2 tests I have listed in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483381/test-if-an-alias-is-a-template-in-d-2-0/5491600#5491600)

```
import std.algorithm : startsWith, canFind;

template isTemplate(alias B) {
    enum isTemplate = !__traits(compiles, {auto x=B;})      // excludes values
                   && !__traits(compiles, {B x;})           // excludes types
                   && __traits(compiles, {alias B x;})      // excludes instance members
                   && !B.stringof.startsWith("module ", "package ") // excludes modules
                   && !B.stringof.canFind("!(");             // excludes instantiated templates
}
```

The 2 tests that have failed like:

```
struct Inner2(string U="!(") {}
static assert(isTemplate(Inner2));
```

If you are sure the template won't have a default argument containing `"...!(..."` I think it is safe to use.

Comment: Wow... it's not terribly pretty but it seems to work! I've been trying to see if I can find any counterexamples, and so far, nope! +1 I'll probably accept it soon if I don't see prettier solutions. :) (The default argument thing always nags me with `stringof`, though...)

Comment: By the way, you can rewrite `__traits(compiles, { B x; })` as `is(B)`. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
template isTemplate(alias T, Args...)
{
    enum bool isTemplate = __traits(compiles, T!(Args));
}
```

this also puts additional constraint - it must be template which can be instantiated with given arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't really help, because the entire reason I asked this question was **precisely** that I do *not* know what the arguments need to be. :(

Answer (score 1):

This code is applying operator address-of '&' which is not applicable to templates, to identify template identifier.

```
struct S (T) {
    int a;
    int foo () () {}
    int xyz (A) (A a) {}
    void bar (T t) {}
}

void main () {
    S!(int) s;
    foreach (m; __traits(allMembers, S!(int)))
        writeln (m, " is template: ", !__traits(compiles, mixin("&s." ~ m)));
}
```

output is:

```
a is template: false
foo is template: true
xyz is template: true
bar is template: false
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will get rvalues wrong, since they don't have addresses either.

Comment: This will also get the name of a type wrong, because you can't take the address of a class: `struct S { struct T { } } pragma(msg, __traits(compiles, &S.T));` prints `false`. :(

Answer (score 1):

A [template alias parameter](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/template.html#TemplateAliasParameter) can accept many things: variables, custom types, modules, templates and literals.

So that `isTemplate` should pass the following test cases:

```
struct FooS(T) {
    struct Inner {}
    struct Inner2(string U="!(") {}
    int func(U)() { return 0; }
    int bar;
}
FooS!int foo;

class FooC { int x; }
union FooU { int x;}
enum FooE { x }
interface FooI { int x(); }

template FooT(T) {
    struct Inner {}
    struct Inner2(string U="!(") {}
    int func(U)() { return 0; }
    int bar;
}

static assert(! isTemplate!0 );
static assert(! isTemplate!"0" );
static assert(! isTemplate!0.0f );
static assert(! isTemplate!'0' );
static assert(! isTemplate!'!' );
static assert(! isTemplate!"module std.stdio" );
static assert(! isTemplate!null );
static assert(! isTemplate!true );
static assert(! isTemplate!__FILE__ );
static assert(! isTemplate!__LINE__ );
static assert(! isTemplate!([]) );
static assert(  isTemplate!FooS );
static assert(! isTemplate!(FooS!int) );
static assert(  isTemplate!(FooS!int.func) );
static assert(! isTemplate!(FooS!int.func!float) );
static assert(! isTemplate!(FooS!int.bar) );
static assert(! isTemplate!(FooS!int.Inner) );
static assert(  isTemplate!(FooS!int.Inner2) );
static assert(! isTemplate!(FooS!int.Inner2!"?") );
static assert(  isTemplate!FooT );
static assert(! isTemplate!(FooT!int) );
static assert(  isTemplate!(FooT!int.func) );
static assert(! isTemplate!(FooT!int.func!float) );
static assert(! isTemplate!(FooT!int.bar) );
static assert(! isTemplate!(FooT!int.Inner) );
static assert(  isTemplate!(FooT!int.Inner2) );
static assert(! isTemplate!(FooT!int.Inner2!"?") );
static assert(! isTemplate!foo );
static assert(  isTemplate!(foo.func) );
static assert(  isTemplate!isTemplate );
static assert(! isTemplate!(isTemplate!isTemplate) );
static assert(! isTemplate!FooC );
static assert(! isTemplate!FooU );
static assert(! isTemplate!FooE );
static assert(! isTemplate!FooI );
static assert(! isTemplate!((int x){return x;}) );
static assert(  isTemplate!(std.stdio.writefln) );
static assert(! isTemplate!(std.stdio) );
static assert(! isTemplate!std );
```

Comment: Yeah, my list wasn't meant to be all-inclusive, it was just a necessary condition. :)
(Is this an answer though?)

Comment: @Mehrdad: No it's not an answer. Just too big to fit in a comment :)